# OGR2OGR EPSG:27700 Shapefile To EPSG:4326 MSSQL Table With Geography

Tags: ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I have been messing around with OGR2OGR for a while now trying to import a shapefile data into an MSSQL table. I am using the OGR2OGR executable that comes packaged with QGIS Wien (GDAL version 1.11.2).

I can get the shapefile to import when using the default Geometry data type however, when I try to output to a Geography data type (required for our GIS Reporting system), I get an output however, it doesn't seem to be able to display correctly in any of the systems that I use.

The command syntax that I am using is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin\ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=<My Database Server>;database=<My Database>;trusted_connection=yes" "<My Shapefile>" --config GDAL_DATA "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\share\gdal" -s_srs "EPSG:27700" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -lco GEOM_TYPE=geography -lco SRID=4326
```

Here is what the output looks like in SSMS:

[image: SSMS Output]

Any ideas?

I have a very limited tool set hence using OGR2OGR in this manner to start with.

Comment: try without -a_srs

Comment: Same results as above...

Comment: @DanielHitchcock did you get this to work? Can you import as geometry then create a new column casting to geography after the import?

Comment: @DPSSpatial No, I never got this to work. As an interim solution, I am using PostGIS as a staging area and re-importing back to MSSQL.

Comment: That's pretty much what we do too..

Comment: @DanielHitchcock what about the casting to geography after the import?\

Comment: @DPSSpatial no, this leads to a similar result. I have made some slight progress - If I install the CLR toolset 'SQLSpatialTools', I can convert the geometry using the function MakeValidGeographyFromGeometry